# About Laravel session in view display

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Excuse me , this quest about login remember the session
decide after login webpage could load

in my login contoller 
I put a variable to session "session_Acc"

```
Session::put('session_Acc', $acc);
```

then I want get in view page after login 
could get use follow?

```
    <li>
    <?php echo Session::get('session_Acc'); ?>
    </li>
```

or should be use

```
return Redirect::to('viewpage')->with(session_Acc', $session_Acc);
```

but Even if use Redirect , it could get session session_Acc
, when I refresh webpage again , Session get nothing ....

but so fantastic , this session could get in another logout controller

how should I do ? thanks

Comment: just to be clear. You wish to store session_Acc in session when user logs in and then be able to access it throughout authenticated user session?

Comment: oh sorry ,  My English is not good , Please correct me in wrong expression or not clear  , I would try my best  ,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it , use `\Session::has('session_Acc')` could get it